# Network requests not captured with Flutter / Firebase-performance

Tags: flutter, firebase-performance

The plugin is correctly installed and provide already some statistics on Firebase console.
But network requests are not listed.
I'm using Dio plugin to manage http request.

Is there any known issues regarding this pb ? does anybody successfully make it work ?

Comment: Did you find any solution ? For Dio it is still not capturing network request.

Answer (score 4):

I wrote a flutter package that allows capturing network requests in case you are using Dio:

```
final dio = Dio();
final performanceInterceptor = DioFirebasePerfomanceInterceptor();
dio.interceptors.add(performanceInterceptor);
```

The package is available here:
https://pub.dev/packages/dio_firebase_performance

The implementation is essentially this one file:
https://github.com/eyeem/dio_firebase_performance/blob/master/lib/src/dio_firebase_performance.dart

This might not be the best implementation but it's a start.

Comment: I used the package, but I can't see any of the network calls made to my server. I can see some records for calls to various google APIs

Answer (score 2):

Firebase Performance Monitoring currently doesn't support automatic network monitoring for Flutter apps.  If this is something you'd like, please [file a feature request](http://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features).

Comment: I have added manual network monitoring using `HttpMetric` as per the example given on the GitHub page, but I'm still not getting any reports on either Android or iOS. Other Firebase features are working fine, eg. analytics, messaging, crash reporting.

Comment: 2021, the problem still exists